# Shortcut to open a new window in word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

With increasing screen sizes and widths, and with figures in papers often at the far end, it becomes increasingly useful to open two instances of a word file side-by-side.

Is there a shortcut to achieve this by keyboard (as fast as possible) rather than clicking the icon as shown below? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't have a current shortcut.

Go to **File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Keyboard Shortcuts** and assign one. In the new dialogue on the left, select `Categories:`  **View Tab** and right: `Commands:` **WindowsNewWindow**.